# Application Lifecycle Management for small university software project

Tags: gratis, software-development, project-management

I gonna participate in a software engineering practical course in which we have to execute a software project in groups with 5 members. The project duration is the whole semester, hence 3 1/2 months

In order to track the progress of the project I would like to use an Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) Software. I would like to insert requirements, specifications, bugs, defects and so on in this software.

Furthermore I would like to create effort estimations, GANTT charts and milestones with this software.

**So my question is, do you know an free ALM software suited for smaller projects?**

"Nice to have features" of the software:

- .) Easy to install on a webspace (or space in the web provided by the
  software creator, like it is the case in GitHub 4 example.)
- .) Accessible with a browser (like Polarion ALM for example)
- .) PDF or WORD export of work items (requirments and so on)
- .) If not accessible with a browser, it should be easy to install an
  Mac OS, Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally wouldn’t post an answer with something that I haven't used extensively. I have only been using [this](http://endeavour-mgmt.sourceforge.net/) a few weeks, but it does look good. It say that it is Agile, but I have no problems using it for waterfall.

> Endeavour Agile ALM features support for Use Cases, Iterations,
>   Project Plan, Change Requests, Defect Tracking, Test Cases, Test
>   Plans, Tasks, Document management, Reports and many other process
>   artifacts. It has been designed with the priority in mind to be easy
>   to use, intuitive and above all realistic by avoiding unnecessary
>   features that might increase complexity.

Btw,

> Endeavour Agile ALM is delivered to the end user through your favorite
>   web browser providing a graphical user interface with rich client
>   capabilities and a look and feel similar to traditional desktop
>   applications, it runs on Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Apple
>   Safari, Google Chrome and Opera.

And, yes, it has Gantt charts and defect reports and the other things you asked for.

I am trying this to see if a single application can replace a group of specialized applications; I am not yet convicted, but YMMV

Comment: Yo Mawg (yo dawg lol), I should kiss your feet because you posted a solution that is really that specific kind of ALM software I have been looking for.
I will try it out and see if it fits my needs.